# Is @FindBy (id = 'blabla') same thing as //*[@id='blabla]

Tags: selenium, xpath, katalon-studio

I decided to give a try to Katalon and got this question because Katalon Studio, when user choose "locate by attribute 'id' " it shows that `//*[@id='blabla']` will be used to locate element. But as for me it looks like variation of xPath. So i wonder, when in JAVA - Selenium i write `@findBy (id='blabla')` - under the hood selenium convert it to `//*[@id = 'blabla']` ???

Could`t find answer

Google, forums, katalon docs

**UPDATE:**
I want to know if this two methods are exactly the same. 1. Will it take same amount of time to find element? 2. Are both of methods going to start looking for element from top of the DOM ?

Answer (score 4):

Functionally these all do the same thing:

- The `@FindBy(id = "foo")` annotation
- `driver.findElement(By.id("foo"))`
- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'foo']"))`
- `driver.findElement(By.css("#foo"))`

They all find an element by its Id.

I'm not sure what that translates to in API calls to the Selenium Server, but [Selenium is open source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client). Have a look for yourself.

The `@FindBy(...)` annotation is defined in [FindBy.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.java), which inherits from [AbstractFindByBuilder](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/AbstractFindByBuilder.java). Trace through the code and you'll figure it out.

Comment: While the end result may be the same, they each find an element using the ID, functionally they are NOT the same. The call goes to the browser driver and it interprets and executes the locator. XPath and CSS selectors are exclusive but I have seen in some cases (don't remember specifics) where locating an element by ID is converted into a CSS selector, `#<id>`. How each locator is translated can depend on the browser, etc. that's generally why Selenium contributors highly recommend using ID, name, and CSS selector because they are most universally consistent where XPath is not.

Comment: @JeffC:  Please cite an example justifying your assertion that XPath is in any way inconsistent.

Comment: @kjhughes I've heard it a few times... a couple times at a Selenium conference (can't remember details but it was the seleniumconf a couple years ago in Austin and I'm pretty sure at least one of them was a contributor, maybe Simon Stewart?) and read it elsewhere. Simple googling found several questions and answers but I didn't look long enough to find something from an "official" source.

Comment: @kjhughes Where I've seen it is Chrome vs IE11. I don't remember all the details but it was using the predecessor axis. In Chrome the indices started at the top of the page but in IE it started at the element. So in Chrome [1] was the first matching element where in IE11 [1] was the immediate predecessor.

Comment: @Greg it does not answer my question still. I`m not wondering if i will get the same result, but if it`s exactly the same method.
Would it Take same amount of time to find element if page is complex ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the equivalent. (But it could depend on the particular Selenium bindings)

If to look into `By` class of Selenium Java library there you can see the code like this:

```
public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
    return context instanceof FindsById ? ((FindsById)context).findElementsById(this.id) : ((FindsByXPath)context).findElementsByXPath(".//*[@id = '" + this.id + "']");
}
```

A single element lookup just reuses lookup of a collection.